# DialogFlow external api calling - result is always object Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Below is the method from index.js

```
function costOfItemHandler(agent) {
    const itemName = agent.parameters.foodItem;
    const url = "https://fast-beach-13460.herokuapp.com/Eatery";
    return axios.get(url)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log('result is '+ result);   
        });
```

In the log it is coming textPayload: "result is [object Object]".
Where as when I am browsing the url it is giving proper response.

Comment: where do you call the function

Comment: in dialogflow inline editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log('result is ', result);
```

If you append an object to a string it returns [object, Object].